# How to run the a[i] == 0 statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to print if else statement. the **else if** which is greater is executing but **a[i]==0** is not executing. How to deal with that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int nl, i, j, count=0;
    printf("Enter the number of values: ");
    scanf("%d",&nl);

    int a[nl];
    for(i=0; i<nl; i++){
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i]<nl){
            printf("Less than\n");
        }
        else if(a[i]>nl){
            printf("Greater than\n");
        }
        else if(a[i]==0){
            printf("Equal\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Abra No, that's not in the slightest related... the OP isn't trying to initialize a VLA.

Comment: if `nl` is `5` and `a[i]` is `0` then `a[i]<nl` will be executed.

Comment: If you want to check for equality against nl, why are you checking against `0`?!

Comment: I tried else statement also but it is not working.

Comment: @Abra Yeah it is, welcome to the year 1999. Might be time to update your C knowledge a bit.

Comment: Please provide the input, the output and the expected output. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want if I press 0 in input then it gave me message of equal

Comment: @Abra Try a standard compliant C compiler instead of a non-compliant C++ compiler?

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`. There might be some `'\n'` left in input buffer...

Answer (score 5):

It's a logic flaw. `a[i]==0` should be `a[i]==nl`. Or you could just write `else {`.

Comment: Neither **a[i] == nl** is working nor **else {** statement is working.

Comment: @RedMailers "Not working" meaning what? What input are you giving the program and what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

It is a logic based problem if you are structuring your code for checking all the being equal, being less than, being greater than cases than the last else if must be like:

```
else if(a[i] == n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, OP states:

> I want if I press 0 in input then it gave me message of equal

When zero is entered, it is first tested with if (a[i]else clauses are never evaluated.

If you want an input of zero to print “Equal” and not to print “Less than”, then you must put `if (a[i] == 0)` first and follow it by `else (a[i] < nl)`.

If you want an input of zero to print both "Equal" and “Less than”, then you should change `else if (a[i]==0)` to `if (a[i] == 0)`, so that `if (a[i] == 0)` is always evaluated, not just as an `else` condition for the preceding `if`.